# Alert command within php not working?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I want to pass a variable in header .if the variable is exist than give an alert.
but its not working
login.php

```
<?php
include "db.php";
$user=$_POST['t1'];
$pass=$_POST['t2'];
$result=mysql_query("select * from registor where username='$user'")or die(mysql_error());
$row=mysql_fetch_row($result);
if($user=='' || $pass==''){
header("location:account.php?wrong");
}
?>
```

account.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['wrong']))
{
?>
<script>alert(Please enter detials !!);</script>
<?php
}
if(isset($_GET['user']))
{
?>
<script>alert(Now, Login Please !!);</script><?php
}
?>
```

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: Look at the code delivered to the browser. Is it the code you expect? Look at your browser's JavaScript error console. What does it say? Don't just chuck a pile of PHP up and say "it does't work".

Answer (score 6):

You need quotes around strings :

```
<script>alert("Now, Login Please !!");</script><?php
```

But you should have seen the error in the [console](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console). Whenever you have something not working client side, *always* look at the console first.

Answer (score 0):

You're actually passing nothing in your header. Make it like this and it'll work:

```
header("location:account.php?wrong=wrong");
```

and use single or double qoutes in your alert message:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['wrong']))
{
?>
<script>alert('Please enter detials !!');</script>
<?php
}
if(isset($_GET['user']))
{
?>
<script>alert('Now, Login Please !!');</script><?php
}
?>
```